# Generics and Wildcards in Java using a static function - "not applicable for the arguments" error

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I can't figure out what's wrong with the following code, specifically, why isn't `<A extends ClassA>` equivalent to `<? extends ClassA>`.

Shouldn't `bar()` be able to call `foo()`?

The compiler says **The method foo(...) is not applicable for the arguments (...)** 
(the exact error is specified in a comment below)

```
static class ClassA {};
static class ClassB<A extends ClassA> {};

private static <A extends ClassA> Collection<ClassB<A>> foo(Collection<ClassB<A>> as) {
    return as;
}

private Collection<ClassB<? extends ClassA>> bar(Collection<ClassB<? extends ClassA>> as) {
    // Error:
    // The method foo(Collection<ClassB<A>>) is not applicable 
    // for the arguments (Collection<ClassB<? extends ClassA>>)
    return foo(as);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure `<A extends Blah>` is valid syntax? i only use `<? extends Blah>` for the producer generic.

Comment: @fas: Yes, it is.  That's generic parameter _declaration_.

Comment: @fas: Generic parameters can have any name you want.

Comment: @SLaks: just saw it in this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html, always thought `T` was special like `?`, but there's an `U` in there as well

Comment: If you plan to use the generic <T extends A> in several methods is better that you define your generic at class level rather than define a generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pass something of type `Collection<ClassB<? extends ClassA>>` into something of type `Collection<ClassB<A>>`. They are not compatible.

In order for two generic types to be compatible, their type parameters, if neither is a wildcard, must match *exactly*. Here, the type parameters are `ClassB<? extends ClassA>` and `ClassB<A>` (for some `A`); neither is a wildcard, and they can never be exactly the same -- no matter what `A` is, it stands in for a specific type. It is true that `ClassB<A>` (whatever `A` is) will be a *subtype* of `ClassB<? extends ClassA>`; but that is irrelevant -- just like `String` is a subtype of `Object` but `Collection<String>` and `Collection<Object>` are not compatible.

If you make `foo()` slightly more generic, so that the generic parameter is at the top level:

```
private static <T extends ClassB<? extends ClassA>> Collection<T> foo(Collection<T> as) {
    return as;
}
```

Then you can use capture to do this:

```
private Collection<? extends ClassB<? extends ClassA>> bar(Collection<? extends ClassB<? extends ClassA>> as) {
    return foo(as);
}
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand what you mean when you say _whatever `A` is_. In my example I explicitly specified `<A extends ClassA>` (which I expect to be the equivalent of `<? extends ClassA>`).

Comment: @nivs: suppose `A` is `String`. Is `ClassB<String>` *exactly the same* as `ClassB<? extends ClassA>`? No. Therefore, `Collection<ClassB<String>>` is not compatible with `Collection<ClassB<? extends ClassA>>` (neither is a subtype of the other).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why ... but you need to add a generic type to the second method :)

```
private <T extends ClassA> Collection<ClassB<T>> bar(Collection<ClassB<T>> as) {
    return foo(as);
}
```

Comment: here's some docu: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html

Comment: yeah, but then if they were to do that, what's the point of having `bar`?